# Removing unwanted margin/padding

Tags: html, css

I cant get rid of a margin or a padding on my website.
[image]
I pointed the margin that I don't want with the red arrow and the picture below is showing how it should look like:
[image]
Here is my website with the problem: http://testy2.comoj.com/

Could you also help me making 3 rows and 4 columns of images on this slide please?

Comment: Can you post your coding?

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 problems:

**1.** In your HTML,

```
<section id="one" class="main style2 right dark fullscreen" style="padding-top: 395px; padding-bottom: 395px;">
```

Remove the `style="padding-top: 395px; padding-bottom: 395px;"`

**2.** In your CSS, your `.main.style2` selector has the following:

```
padding: 10em 0 10em 0;
```

Fix both these problems and you'll have what you want.

Comment: Would be great if there would be such a thing as style="padding-top: 395px; padding-bottom: 395px; :/ Can't see anything like that

Comment: Looks like they are automatically created. I can seem them in chrome developer tools, but I can't see them in your html source.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you automatically create those values.

`<section style=padding-bot:0; padding-top:0;" .... </section>`

Take care.